# Let X be a continuous non-negative random variable with density function f, and let Y = X^n. Find the probability density function of Y

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a continuous non-negative random variable with density function $f$, and let $Y = X^n$. Find the probability density function of $Y$

I have:

$$F_y(y)=P(X^n\le y)$$

- if $y<0$, then $P(X^n\le y)=0$, so $F_y(y)=0$, if $y<0$
- if $y>=0$, then $P(X^n\le y)=P[|X|\le y^{1/n}]=P[-y^{1/n}\le x\le y^{1/n}]$

  So

  $F_y(y)=F_x[Y^{1/n}]-F_x[-y^{1/n}]$, $y\ge0$

Answer (score 2):

The random variable $X$ is, we are told, **non-negative.**

Let $f(x)$ be the density function of $X$, and let $F(x)$ be the cumulative distribution function of $X$. Let $F_Y(y)$ be the cdf of $Y$. For $y\gt 0$, we have
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(X^n\le y)=\Pr(X\le y^{\frac{1}{n}})=F(y^{\frac{1}{n}}).$$

For the density function $f_Y(y)$ of $y$, differentiate. For $y\gt 0$, by the Chain Rule, we get
$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{n}y^{\frac{1}{n}-1}f(y^{\frac{1}{n}}).$$