# What is wrong with my solution for finding $f_Y$ if $Y = X^n$?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I have a solution to the following problem without using all the assumptions,  and I am wondering if my solution is wrong as a result.

> Let $X$ be a continuous nonnegative random variable with density function $f_X$, and let $Y = X^n$. Find $f_Y$, the probability density function of $Y$ in terms of $f_X$.

This question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539631/let-x-be-a-continuous-non-negative-random-variable-with-density-function-f-and) using the cumulative distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$, and this solution uses the fact $X$ is non-negative. I think I have a different solution that arrives at the same answer without using the fact $X$ is non-negative as shown below:

Since $Y = X^n$, we have $dy  = nx^{n-1}dx$ and so
\begin{align*}
f_Y(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y)\, dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y)\, (\frac{dy}{nx^{n-1}})\\
&= \frac{1}{nx^{n-1}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y)\,dy\\
&=  \frac{f_X(x)}{nx^{n-1}}
\end{align*}

Why is this solution wrong, or where do I need the assmption $X\ge 0$?

Edit: From my interpretation of Ingix's answer, I think a better solution would be:

\begin{align*}
f_Y(y) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x, y)\, dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x, y)\, dx\tag{Since $x\ge 0$}\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x, y)\, (\frac{dy}{nx^{n-1}})\tag{Using the subtitution $y = x^n$}\\
&= \frac{1}{nx^{n-1}}\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x, y)\,dy\\
&=  \frac{f_X(x)}{nx^{n-1}}\tag{as $f(x,y) = 0$ for $y\neq x^n$}
\end{align*}

Comment: Your solution depends on $n$ as for $n$ even $Y$ will always be positive, whilst for $n$ odd, there is a bijections between $X$ and $Y.$

Comment: @WillM. I dont quite understand what you mean

Comment: Well, then there is nothing I can do to help you. Sorry and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To see that your formula is (generally) incorrect for random $Xs$ that can be negative and even $n$, consider $X_1$ being a random variable uniformely distributed on the interval $[0,1]$ and $X_2$ uniformely distributed on the interval $[-1,1]$. Obviously $f_{X_1}(t) = 1 = 2 f_{X_2}(t)$ for any $t \in [0,1]$.

However, both $Y_i=X_i^2 (i=1,2)$ have the same distribution, because $Y_i$ depends only on $|X_i|$, and both $|X_1|$ and $|X_2|$ have the same distribution (uniform on $[0,1]$).

As has been established, your end result is correct for non-negative $X$, so your formula will correctly get $f_{Y_1}(y)$, but incorrectly get $f_{Y_2}(y)$, because the $f_{X_{1,2}}(x)$ are different but the result should be the same (and the formula is linear (so injective) in $f_{X}(x))$.

The reason for this error is that in order to do the differential substitution you did, going from $dx$ to $dy$, you also need to transform the integral bounds, and in that process you need to establish the areas where your transformation function is monotone, to possibly split the integral into more than one.

For odd $n$, this is not a problem, as $y=x^n$ is increasing. When only considering non-negative $X$, this isn't a problem for even $n$, as the integral effectively goes from $0$ to $\infty$, and $y=x^n$ is increasing in that interval as well. But it falls down if you have potentially negative values **and** even $n$.

Another hint that something is not as it should be with your formula is that for even $n$, there are two $x$ that satisfy $y=x^n$ for a given posiive $y$. Which one should it be in your formula, considering the density function might be different for them?

Comment: Ah this makes sense. Considering this by changing the bounds to $0$ to $\infty$ and noting this is for non-negative $x$, is my formulation correct?

Comment: I'm not totally sure. For starters, what is your $f(x,y)$? If it is supposed to be the density of the common distribution of $(Y,X)$, then that is not a real valued function, because the density must be 0 for $y \neq x^n$ and then the integral can't be anything else than 0.

Comment: Yes, $f(x,y)$ is the joint density function of $X$ and $Y$. I have edited my solution based off my interpretation of what you said, does this fix it?

Comment: See, there is not joint density function of $X$ and $Y$, at least not in the sense as a real valued function. It simply does not exist! You need to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) to find the mathematical groundwork that makes it possible to work as though it does. That's why your integral solution produced the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is wrong because you seem to pull the relation $f(x,y)dx = f(x,y)\frac{dy}{nx^{n-1}}$ out of a hat(I'm not entirely sure if it's true, it may be). Before using such a strong assumption about X and Y you would have to ***justify it*** and the only thing we know about f(x,y) is that it is the derivative of $P(X \leq x, Y \leq y)$ so we seem to get back to the solution in the link, sort of.

Comment: I would consider it pretty trivial that $y =x^n\iff dy = nx^{n-1}dx$ unless im missing something. Nonetheless, i revised my post justifying that line

Comment: @Lindstorm: I agree that $y=x^n$ implies that $dy=nx^{n-1}dx$(this is just a simple relation between some non-random functions), but there is no reason why $Y=X^n$ would imply that $f(x,y)dx = f(x,y)\frac{dy}{nx^{n-1}}$ a priori. This is completely different. It's a relation between random variables and between their pdf's. Unless you justify this starting from what a pdf means, it seems to me that your proof is very much incomplete and very confusing.